# Craft 3 Plugins - Setting Template Path To Site Templates

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

In Craft 2, if you have a **plugin** that needs to load a view from the **site templates** directory, you could just go:

```php
# Set the template context to site templates.
$path = craft()->path->getSiteTemplatesPath();
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($path);

# Now we can load sweet templates from the sites templates dir, not the plugin one.
craft()->templates->render("/path/to/particular/site/template");
```

I'm struggling with doing this in a **Craft 3 plugin**. I thought I was on the right track with the below, but the context isn't updating.

```php
# Set the template context to site templates.
$path = Craft::$app->getPath()->getSiteTemplatesPath();
Craft::$app->getView()->setTemplatesPath($path);

# Or this seems like it might do the same? 
# Craft::$app->getView()->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);

# Render the view!
Craft::$app->getView()->render("/path/to/particular/site/template")
```

This results in explosions. It shows the error:

> Unable to resolve view file for view
>   '/path/to/particular/site/template': no active view context.

Setting the template context is the bit that's not working. It's still looking at the plugin template directory.

Answer (score 7):

Ok I've made sense of this - if you set the view template mode/context to site, then use the view **renderTemplate()** method (not render) it works.

So this is how you achieve the same thing in **Craft 3**.

```php
# Set the template context to the site mode.
Craft::$app->getView()->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);

# Now using the renderTemplate() method, it will work.
$html = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate("/path/to/particular/site/template");
```

Edit: Lenka commented pointing out there is actually some [official documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#rendering-templates) on this.

Comment: What worked for me was Craft::$app->getView()->setTemplateMode('site')
as per the documentation on https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#method-settemplatemode

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, but I'm a new participant, so I can't add it.
I recommend the official documentation page https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#rendering-templates where you can find all the variants how to updating Rendering Templates from Craft2 to Craft3.